# An idea for this difficult integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, inverse-function, trigonometric-integrals

I am being stuck in caculating this integral: $$J=\int_{-\tfrac{1}{2}}^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\dfrac{\arccos x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}(1+e^{-x})}dx$$ I tried to change to another variable: $x = - t$ then $dx = - dt$, also I got: $$J=\int_{-\tfrac{1}{2}}^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\dfrac{\arccos(-t)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}(1+e^t)}dt=\int_{-\tfrac{1}{2}}^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\dfrac{\arccos(-x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}(1+e^x)}dx.$$ Therefore $$2J=\int_{-\tfrac{1}{2}}^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\left[\dfrac{\arccos x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}(1+e^{-x})}+\dfrac{\arccos(-x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}(1+e^x)}\right]dx=\int_{-\tfrac{1}{2}}^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\dfrac{e^x\arccos x+\arccos(-x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}(1+e^x)}dx$$
The numerator looks very complex and I really do not know how to do next. Can you guys give me some ideas ?

Comment: Maybe $x = \cos u$?

Comment: I also tried that but it was no use.

Comment: try x = -t substitution and then some algebraic manipulation which will cause the exponential in the denominator to cancel so the integral will come out as $\frac{-1}{4} \left(\arccos(x)\right)^{2}$

Comment: You can use $\arccos(-x)=\pi-\arccos x$ to clean up the numerator a bit, though that doesn't really make things easier.

Comment: Where did you get this?

Comment: In one of my real analysis final term exams

Comment: The approximate result is $0.799484$, but I cannot find a closed form for it.

Comment: @LêTrungKiên, did your exam ask you to get the exact value of the integral  or just an approximation of it by applying for example the Simpson's rule ?

Comment: @Angelo  the test require exact the value of the integral pal.